# Process finished with exit code -1073741515 when calling GLEW functions

Tags: c++, opengl, glew

I've written a basic OpenGL program in C++ which just opens a window. I'm now trying to draw a triangle, but I'm having some issues calling GLEW functions. This is my code with just OpenGL:

```cpp
#include "include/glew.h"
#include "include/glfw3.h"

int main()
{
    GLFWwindow* window;

    if (!glfwInit())
        return -1;

    window = glfwCreateWindow(800, 600, "HelloWorld", nullptr, nullptr);
    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    unsigned int buffer;
    //glGenBuffers(1, &buffer);

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        glfwPollEvents();
    }
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

Uncommenting `glGenBuffers(1, &buffer);`, which is a GLEW function, causes the program to exit with code `-1073741515`. No errors were displayed. I've correctly linked with GLEW, as well as opengl32, gdi32, user32, and shell32. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Windows error `-1073741515` (`0xC0000135`) is `STATUS_DLL_NOT_FOUND`.

Comment: @InfiniteVortex32 Are the dll files in the same folder as the exe? Do you bind glew static or dynamic (dll)

Comment: My output exe is not in the same folder as the DLLs, but making it output to the same folder did not fix the issue. I'm not sure if it's static or dynamic, but I'm linking it using `target_link_directories(helloworld PUBLIC lib)` and `target_link_libraries(helloworld glew32)` in cmake. The DLLs are located in `lib/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to [Initialize GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net/). Call [`glewInit`](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Loading_Library#Initialization_of_GLEW_1.13.0_and_earlier) right after making the OpenGL context current:

```cpp
glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
    return 0;
```

In addition, you have to make sure that the DLL files can be found at runtime. Add a path to the Windows *path* environment variable or place the DLL files in the same directory as the executable.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but unfortunately doing this doesn't fix the error.

Comment: @InfiniteVortex32 So there is another issue related to your system.

Comment: How do I find out what the issue is?

Comment: @InfiniteVortex32 What is your OS?

Comment: Windows 10 64bit

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by adding `glewInit()`, and also moving glew32.dll to my output directory. I just got confused between the lib and dll files, which is why it wasn't working earlier.